# Android 4.2 Emulation from x86 (Intel Atom) to iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, emulation

I was just wondering if it was possible to essentially use a iOS (or indeed other mobile OSes) as a peripheral for the Android SDK's emulator. I'm currently running the emulator on my Macbook pro, but the lack of a touch-screen interface removes from the testing experience.

Currently I do not own an Android (ARM) device (other than a RaspberryPi - which has a v6 processor that cannot run 4.2 for obvious reasons) so I have to run it on my Macbook with the x86 emulator image. However, I do have an old second gen. iPod touch lying around.

Is it possible to emulate Android 4.2 from the x86 emulator image and display it on a iOS device's display AND use the touchscreen interface. Obviously it would have to be plugged directly into the Mac via USB (unless you used some kind of remote desktop app over wi-fi) and would probably require some serious hacking.

All I ask is - is it possible? And if so, is it worth the effort?

(Sorry for any spelling mistakes. My English is atrocious.)

Comment: Theoretically it's probably possible, but I seriously doubt it's worth the effort given you can get a Nexus 7 for $199...

Comment: `#1` - possible, yes; probable/cost effective, no `#2` - your English is excellent